# Multisite get_home_url(); - Getting URL for current site

Tags: php, multisite, template-tags

What would be the replacement for get_home_url() when using a multisite? For example, if I have one theme installed across several sites, and within the theme there are links that need to be specific to the current site.

On my single install, using get_home_url(); would give me http://domain.com/, which was great, and if I moved the theme to a different domain, nothing would be affected. But when I'm using the same theme on a multisite, get_home_url(); gives me http://domain.com/ no matter which site I am currently on. What I would need for each one is domain.com/sitename/. Is there a different tag to use in this case?

Thanks!

EDIT

Can't answer my own question yet, but `<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'url' )?>` was exactly was I was looking for.

Comment: if you need exactlly for multisite use `network_home_url();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'url' )?>` was exactly was I was looking for.

Answer (score 17):

I would recommend you use `home_url()` to get the URL to the front page of the currently viewed site.

If you want to get the main site URL (the network home), use `network_home_url()`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the network home url tag! It was just what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`get_site_url()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_site_url/) in combination with [`get_current_blog_id()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_current_blog_id/).

Answer (score -1):

I have a not "so better", but a solution.

I've tried with your method with the following setup:

- Localhost,
- Using ISS
- Wordpress version 4.1

and to get the right url I changed the `wp-config.php` and added this line:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/wordpress/');*

define('URL_SITE', 'http://'.DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE.PATH_CURRENT_SITE );

define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

I hope that can help someone with this.